# Object.entries in array key

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to display the router name in the component, depending on what the is pathname. My code below works fine, but I don't like that I'm doing `route[1]` in the code. This is hardly legible and I wonder if it can be written better.

routes.js:

```
export default {
  login: {
    name: <FormattedMessage {...loginMessages.login} />,
    path: '/login',
  },
  register: {
    name: <FormattedMessage {...registerMessages.registration} />,
    path: '/register',
  },
  dashboard: {
    name: <FormattedMessage {...dashboardMessages.dashboard} />,
    path: '/dashboard',
  },
};
```

Component:

```
   import { routes } from 'utils'; 
   ...
   {Object.entries(routes).map(
        (route) =>
          route[1].path === pathname && (
            <div key={route[1].path}>{route[1].name}</div>
          ),
      )}
   ...
```

Comment: change `(route) =>` to `({1: route}) =>` then `route.path` or rather `Object.entries` use `Object.values` and if routes is an array why not `routes.map`?

Comment: @AZ_ or `([, route]) =>` seeing how it's an array. Although I'm not sure OP is not using `.values` here if the keys are not needed.

Comment: @VLAZ, yup that also will do the job. :)

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite Component as:

```
import { routes } from 'utils'; 

   ...
   {Object.values(routes).map(
        (route,index) =>
          index == 1 &&         //whatever index you want
          route.path === pathname && (
            <div key={route.path}>{route.name}</div>
          ),
      )}
   ...
```